# PHP+MYSQL+calling procedure from php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have this procedure in mysql :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getPersoane(IN nume_in VARCHAR(50),OUT nume_out VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SELECT nume_complet INTO nume_out
    FROM contacte
    WHERE nume_complet = nume_in;
END//
```

And here is my code for calling procedures:

```
....
$rezultate = mysql_query( 'CALL getPersoane($cautare,@nume_out)' );
$rezultate = mysql_query( 'SELECT @nume_out AS numepers' );
....
```

Why i can't see the results of procedure ?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you did affect two query for the same variable ($rezultate) ,anyways..
You can't see the result of the procedure, because you only put the result in '$rezultate' .
try this :

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($rezultate)) 
     {
       echo $data['Name_of_field'];//
     }
```

i'm sorry if it's not helpful..but i'm pretty sure that the while loop is a good way to display the result of a mysql query/procedure.
and thanks :)

Comment: i tried this but still don't work.the program don't display anything.